# How to modify the database schema of keycloak

Tags: database-design, schema, keycloak

Is there any way to modify or redesign the database of keycloak. In other words, can we integrate our own schema with keycloak. Currently, the existing database is based on a single database and shared schema approach. Can we change it to create a separate database for each tenant?

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. But it will be a quite challenging task and you will introduce many problems, especially for the future Keycloak upgrades.
Better will be to write custom "plugin" for the Keycloak, which will use your existing database. You still need a coding, but it will be cleaner solution: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_user-storage-spi

Comment: Yes I understand it will be quite challenging. The second option seems feasible. Thanks